# How to draw circle or rectangle or arrow in blender video editor?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

I am creating a tutorial and i want to create for example a rectangle to attract the viewers attention

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do (or something similar, as I use this tactic to position more videos for people to click on), you can create a simple box with transparency around it (though make sure that the image format you save it as has support for alpha, png should work):

1. Get your image onto your sequencer (drag in the image, or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>).

[image: General scene]

2. Select your image (Right click), and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> , then choose *Effect Strip*, and then *Transform*.

[image: Effect Strip Transform]

3. Select the Transform block/strip, then over on the right, choose
   *Alpha Over* instead of *Replace*.

[image: Alpha over]

4. Change the position and scale settings on the right, in the *Effect Strip*

[image: Change position and scale]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can simply create an transparent image with a rectangle or arrow and use alpha over to show that image on top of your image strip ?

Comment: I tried to do so, but every time i want to add a bordered rectangle for example i have to take screen shot of my video, go to my image editor and create a rectangle for that potion.